# Microk8s + metallb + ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, microk8s, metallb

Im quite new to kubernetes and Im trying to set up a microk8s test environment on a VPS with CentOS.

What I did:

I set up the cluster, enabled the ingress and metallb

```
microk8s enable ingress
microk8s enable metallb
```

Exposed the ingress-controller service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    name: nginx-ingress-microk8s 
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

Exposed an nginx deployment to test the ingress

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

This is the status of my cluster:

```
NAMESPACE            NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system          pod/hostpath-provisioner-5c65fbdb4f-m2xq6        1/1     Running   3          41h
kube-system          pod/coredns-86f78bb79c-7p8bs                     1/1     Running   3          41h
kube-system          pod/calico-node-g4ws4                            1/1     Running   6          42h
kube-system          pod/calico-kube-controllers-847c8c99d-xhmd7      1/1     Running   4          42h
kube-system          pod/metrics-server-8bbfb4bdb-ggvk7               1/1     Running   0          41h
kube-system          pod/kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-ktv8j        1/1     Running   0          41h
kube-system          pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-6c4568dc68-l4xmg   1/1     Running   0          41h
container-registry   pod/registry-9b57d9df8-xjh8d                     1/1     Running   0          38h
cert-manager         pod/cert-manager-cainjector-5c6cb79446-vv5j2     1/1     Running   0          12h
cert-manager         pod/cert-manager-794657589-srrmr                 1/1     Running   0          12h
cert-manager         pod/cert-manager-webhook-574c9758c9-9dwr6        1/1     Running   0          12h
metallb-system       pod/speaker-9gjng                                1/1     Running   0          97m
metallb-system       pod/controller-559b68bfd8-trk5z                  1/1     Running   0          97m
ingress              pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-f6cdb      1/1     Running   0          65m
default              pod/nginx-deploy-5797b88878-vgp7x                1/1     Running   0          20m

NAMESPACE            NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
default              service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP      10.152.183.1     <none>         443/TCP                      42h
kube-system          service/kube-dns                    ClusterIP      10.152.183.10    <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       41h
kube-system          service/metrics-server              ClusterIP      10.152.183.243   <none>         443/TCP                      41h
kube-system          service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP      10.152.183.225   <none>         443/TCP                      41h
kube-system          service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP      10.152.183.109   <none>         8000/TCP                     41h
container-registry   service/registry                    NodePort       10.152.183.44    <none>         5000:32000/TCP               38h
cert-manager         service/cert-manager                ClusterIP      10.152.183.183   <none>         9402/TCP                     12h
cert-manager         service/cert-manager-webhook        ClusterIP      10.152.183.99    <none>         443/TCP                      12h
echoserver           service/echoserver                  ClusterIP      10.152.183.110   <none>         80/TCP                       72m
ingress              service/ingress                     LoadBalancer   10.152.183.4     192.168.0.11   80:32617/TCP,443:31867/TCP   64m
default              service/nginx-deploy                ClusterIP      10.152.183.149   <none>         80/TCP                       19m

NAMESPACE        NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
kube-system      daemonset.apps/calico-node                         1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux        42h
metallb-system   daemonset.apps/speaker                             1         1         1       1            1           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   97m
ingress          daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>                        65m

NAMESPACE            NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system          deployment.apps/hostpath-provisioner        1/1     1            1           41h
kube-system          deployment.apps/coredns                     1/1     1            1           41h
kube-system          deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers     1/1     1            1           42h
kube-system          deployment.apps/metrics-server              1/1     1            1           41h
kube-system          deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           41h
kube-system          deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           41h
container-registry   deployment.apps/registry                    1/1     1            1           38h
cert-manager         deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector     1/1     1            1           12h
cert-manager         deployment.apps/cert-manager                1/1     1            1           12h
cert-manager         deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook        1/1     1            1           12h
metallb-system       deployment.apps/controller                  1/1     1            1           97m
default              deployment.apps/nginx-deploy                1/1     1            1           20m

NAMESPACE            NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system          replicaset.apps/hostpath-provisioner-5c65fbdb4f        1         1         1       41h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/coredns-86f78bb79c                     1         1         1       41h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-847c8c99d      1         1         1       42h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/metrics-server-8bbfb4bdb               1         1         1       41h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895        1         1         1       41h
kube-system          replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-6c4568dc68   1         1         1       41h
container-registry   replicaset.apps/registry-9b57d9df8                     1         1         1       38h
cert-manager         replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-5c6cb79446     1         1         1       12h
cert-manager         replicaset.apps/cert-manager-794657589                 1         1         1       12h
cert-manager         replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-574c9758c9        1         1         1       12h
metallb-system       replicaset.apps/controller-559b68bfd8                  1         1         1       97m
default              replicaset.apps/nginx-deploy-5797b88878                1         1         1       20m
```

It looks like Metallb works, as the ingress services received an ip from the pool I specified.
Now, when I try to deploy an ingress to reach the nginx deployment, I dont get the ADDRESS:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: ingress-nginx-deploy
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-deploy
          servicePort: 80

NAMESPACE   NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS                       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
default     ingress-nginx-deploy   <none>   test.com                              80      13m
```

An help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There are some ways to fix your `Ingress` so that it would get the IP address.

You can **either**:

- Delete the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` and add `ingressClassName: public` under `spec` section.
- Use the newer example (`apiVersion`) from official documentation that by default will have assigned an `IngressClass`:

  - [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource)

Example of `Ingress` resource that will fix your issue:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-deploy
spec:
  ingressClassName: public 
  # above field is optional as microk8s default ingressclass will be assigned
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-deploy
            port:
              number: 80
```

You can read more about `IngressClass` by following official documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Blog: Improvements to the Ingress API in Kubernetes 1.18](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/)*

I've included more explanation that should shed some additional light on this particular setup.

---

After you apply above `Ingress` resource the output of:

- `$ kubectl get ingress`

Will be following:

```
NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS      ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-deploy   public   test.com   127.0.0.1   80      43s
```

As you can see the `ADDRESS` contains `127.0.0.1`. It's because this particular `Ingress controller` enabled by an addon, binds to your host (`MicroK8S` node) to ports `80`,`443`.

You can see it by running:

- `$ sudo microk8s kubectl get daemonset -n ingress nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller -o yaml`

> A side note!
>
> Look for `hostPort` and `securityContext.capabilities`.

The `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` created by you will work with your `Ingress controller` but it will not be displayed under `ADDRESS` in `$ kubectl get ingress`.

> A side note!
>
> Please remember that in this particular setup you will need to connect to your `Ingress controller` with a `Header` `Host: test.com` unless you have DNS resolution configured to support your setup. Otherwise you will get a `404`.

---

Additional resource:

- *[Github.com: Ubuntu: Microk8s: Ingress with MetalLb issues](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1794)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Configuration: Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/)*

Comment: Thank you Dawid that was really helpful. To be honest I started without the MetalLB, with ingress class = public and the ingress got the 127.0.0.1 address,  I was able to access the Dashboard from outside the machine on the machine public IP address. I started to add TLS with letsencrypt, but had problem 404 when was doing the self check on the /.well-known. Since Im a newbie in Kubernetes, I decided to try something closer to production, with a load balancer in front of it, hoping to finally get the TLS working. Probably, the problem of TLS was not even because of the missing load balancer.

Comment: Regarding security, I have a vpn server and I was thinking to set up firewalld to allow http and https services only for the particular vpn ip.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using the header Host? it is quite annoying :)

Comment: @Green Delete the `test.com` from the `spec.rules.host` (`host` should look like this: `host: `).

Comment: still having problems with ingress, LetsEncrypt and gitlab integration. Im going to reset my microk8s cluster and restart from scratch. But thanks for the hints!